# Cannot deserialize instance of textarea from VALUE_STRING value

Tags: apex, apexrest

Iam transferring data through integration

I am using Standard REST API https://instancename/services/data/v49.0/sobjects/Objectname/

In JSON payload we are sending text area fields along with other types of fields

when we are sending rich text area am getting errors.

**Getting these Error
**Error: 400 Bad Request [{"message":"Cannot deserialize instance of textarea from VALUE_STRING value****

snippet: This is how I am Passing the text area in a payload
I have used **escapeHtml** method that not Working

```
if (emailService.CommentsCopy__c != null) {                             
   jsonPayload += '"CommentsCopy__c":"<p></p>' + emailService.CommentsCopy__c + '<p></p>",';
}
```

In both orgs CommentsCopy__c is a rich text area field.

How can I resolve This Error?
Any Suggestions Please

Comment: Have you checked this? - https://trailhead.salesforce.com/trailblazer-community/feed/0D54V00007T4NuSSAV

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not properly escaping the field, so certain characters could cause this error. At a basic level, you could probably fix this with just:

```
+ JSON.serialize(emailService.CommentsCopy__c) +
```

It is usually advised that you do not manually build JSON strings, because it is easy to make mistakes. Instead, it would be recommended to use `JSON.serialize` across an entire `Map<String, Object>`, which will protect against accidentally not escaping characters correctly.

Comment: Thanks @sfdcbox  .  Used JSONGenerator Class to serialize  errors fixed.